# Pandas.plot(kind = 'bar') returns line plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm trying to produce a bar plot using pandas plot function but it keeps returning line plot, would someone please assist me in fixing this. Also, how do I auto-label plots with player names.

```
# Dummy Data Frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player': ['A', 'B']*5, 
          'plActual' : np.random.randn(10), 
          'plPredict' : np.random.randn(10)}, 
         pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods = 10))

# subplots by player
df.groupby('Player').plot(kind='bar', subplots = True);
```

I am using version 0.17.1 of Pandas. The above produces the following plots -

[image]

Comment: Do you want a histogram?

Comment: I just want vertical bars instead of lines - 2 bars for each day (predict, actual). Thanks!

Comment: It is probably confused because you have two numeric axis. Bar plots usually have a categorical axis. Try converting one of your axis to a string so that the bar plot knows where to put the bars.

Answer (score 1):

```
players = {'A': 'Player A', 'B': 'Player B'}

for player in df.Player.unique():
    df.loc[df.Player == player].plot(kind='bar', title=players.get(player))
```

[image]
[image]